# Multiprocessing IndexError out of range

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having a issue with `multiprocessing.pool` on the following piece of code:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = compile_paths()
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    r = pool.map(compile_,files,chunksize=len(files))
```

That gives out:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-06f23d3cf8fa>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rafael/scripts/ETL/read.py', wdir='C:/Users/rafael/scripts/ETL')

  File "C:\Users\rafael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\rafael\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rafael/scripts/ETL/read.py", line 185, in <module>
    r = pool.map(compile_,files,chunksize=len(files))

  File "C:\Users\rafael\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "C:\Users\rafael\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This `compile_` is a function that reads the paths from files and saves then in a folder. The problem is that I put a `print("Howdy")` at the start of the function and it's never printed. Moreover, I made smaller `files` just to test it out and it never leaves the `pool.map()` function.

Comment: Why do I see Ipython there? Are you trying to multiprocess with IPython?

Comment: The true answer is I don't know. I started fooling around with multiprocessing today.

Comment: Okay. Well it looks like you might be and from what I understand you can't do it with IPython. Either way, if you're fooling around, start by just replacing the pool.map with an ordinary for loop applying your function to each element of the array. Only once you have it working normally, then try and multiprocess it. And then try run the script from a shell of some sort with cpython, not ipython. Looks like you're on Windows as well which can come with it's own issues (since processes are an OS layer thing)

Comment: Why are you passing chunksize as the list's length? You're basically sending all files to one process and lose the point of using a pool...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, it was a mistake. The IPython was one of the issue, but also I was passing a function that dealt with a list of fnames not one fname.